# Identify Object Type(i.e. Class)

Tags: java, file, object

I am trying to identify the Type of an Object from the class definition :

For example,

```
class MyCustomClass{

    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();

    public void method(HttpServletRequest request){
        String s1="Hello";
        request.setAttribute(s1);
        request.setAttribute(obj1);     

    }       



    public void method2(HttpServletRequest request){
        Class2 obj2 = new Class2();
        request.setAttribute(obj1);     
        request.setAttribute(obj2);
    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

In this I need to identify the Type of all those Object which are getting set in request.setAttribute() whether it is primary on not along with scanning the whole Java File. I tried reading Java File using FileReader but in that case I am not able to fetch the Object Type. Any solution to this will be of great help.

Thanks

Reference Post(Asking Further) : [Read Complete Java Class Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755416/read-complete-java-class-implementation)

Comment: You either could (or maybe even should) use generic type brackets (<ObjectClass>) or you can use the Class files methods to access information about the name (Class#getName eg).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read and parse the above code to determine what type of class obj1, s1 etc are?

Comment: @Luftbaum : I agree with your point. But in that case I won't be able to scan the whole Java File Definition(Implementation). I asked that too as a Reference Post.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to write a static code analyzer. Please explain a bit more about what you want this for/what you are trying to achieve, why is reflection not enough in your case?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : Correct. I wanna to identify all the Object Types which are getting set in setAttribute() method alongwith scanning the whole Java Definition.

Comment: @Hulk : Somewhere yes. I am trying to scan my whole code repository to identify where is request.setAttribute(object) method is invoked and wanna to identify the type of Object set into that. Just to serialize or convert it into JSON manually as Jackson2 and Gson Libraries fails in such cases.

Comment: Most JSON libraries just use reflection for this - in which way what they are doing is not enough for you? Writing a static analyzer is not a small task - you need at least a tokenizer and a parser for java, and even then they are mostly useful for generating hints about potential issues, less so for directly generating code or taking runtime decisions.

Comment: I agree with @Hulk and I think this question should be closed since it's to broad.

Comment: @hulk : Agreed. Can't we write a simple Code Analyzer which can scan the whole repository and check for condition to return an object? I am stuck while identifying the type of an Object from a Object Variable name.

Comment: @DipenShah if you just need the declared type at compile time, that is possible, but a bit harder than it seems at the first glance because of generics etc., and the `var` keyword in new code. If you need the precise runtime type, that is impossible to statically determine in the general case. Even if you scan your entire repository, there are also external sources for types (runtime and 3rd party libraries), synthetic types generated by the compiler (e.g. lambdas, method references...), and classes can also be loaded dynamically at runtime via classloaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible as mentioned by @Joakim and @Luftbaum. The way I have done that is by multiple scan.